# How to dynamicaly change data in dropdown on change of text box Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a text box and dropdown. Text box contains the province name and the dropdown contains the the cities. I want to chnage the province of the text box and dynamically change the dropdown related to the text in the textbox. I am using codeigniter framework. My view is as follows and I get the data from the database. I think there is a problem with the **onchange** or that kind of event of the text box (this code worked for change event for another dropdown. But it is not working for the taxt box- so the other logic is ok but I cant figure out the event of the textbox. What is the right event for the text box ? My code

```
<script> .........................<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $('#provincial').on('input',function()
        { 

            var id_provincia = $('#provincial').val();
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json", // I ADDED THIS LINE
                    url:"tenda/get_comuni/"+id_provincia,
                    success: function(comuni)
                    {
                        $('#comuni').empty();
                        $.each(comuni,function(id_comune, nome_comune)
                        {
                            var opt = $('<option />');
                            opt.val(id_comune);
                            opt.text(nome_comune);
                            $('#comuni').append(opt);
                        });            
                    }
                });
        });
    });  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php $comuni['#'] = 'seleziona'; ?>
<div id="tenda">
            <label for="provincia">provincia: </label><?php echo form_dropdown('id_provincia', $provincie, '#', 'id="provincia"'); ?>
           <?php echo form_input('id_provincial','', '#', 'id="provincial"'); ?>
            <label for="comune">comune: </label><?php echo form_dropdown('id_comune', $comuni, '#', 'id="comuni"'); ?><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a textbox you can use [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) or [onchange](http://api.jquery.com/change/) (fired when element loses focus) events.

```
$('#provincial').keyup(function(event){...});
```

If you want to sent POST request when you press enter button, you can handle it using this code snippet:

```
if (event.which == 13) {
  event.preventDefault();
  .. // DO POST Request
}
```

Comment: my text box is as follows... <?php echo form_input('id_provincial','', '#', 'id="provincial"'); ?>    and the sloution is not working. Is there any thing wrong with this ?